# Quick way to avoid error for byte values <0 or >255

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim col As Color 'the color I check
    Dim ref As Byte  'the color what I expect

    Select Case col.R
        Case ref
            'code
        Case ref - 3 To ref + 3
            'code
        Case ref - 6 To ref + 6
            'code
        Case ref - 10 To ref + 10
            'code
        Case Else
            'code
    End Select
```

Ref - X can be < 0 (error) or ref + X can be >255 (error).

Is there a quick way to avoid errors without lots of  If... then... else?

Comment: What are you doing with the edge cases, < 0 and > 255?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the bytes to `Integer` for the comparison to avoid overflows:

```vb
Dim col As Color 'the color I check
Dim ref As Byte  'the color what I expect
Dim intRef As Integer = CInt(ref)
Select Case CInt(col.R)
    Case intRef
        'code
    Case intRef - 3 To intRef + 3
        'code
    Case intRef - 6 To intRef + 6
        'code
    Case intRef - 10 To intRef + 10
        'code
    Case Else
        'code
End Select
```

Note that both `CInt()` casts are redundant and can be removed. I just added them to make the intent clearer. Since `intRef` is typed as `Integer`, the bytes will automatically be converted to `Integer`. [Widening conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/widening-and-narrowing-conversions) are done implicitly, even with `Option Strict On`.

or simpler

```vb
Select Case Math.Abs(CInt(col.R) - ref)
    Case 0
        'code
    Case <= 3
        'code
    Case <= 6
        'code
    Case <= 10
        'code
    Case Else
        'code
End Select
```

Since `CInt(col.R)` is an `Integer`, `ref` will automatically be expanded to `Integer` for the subtraction.

Comment: At one point, it was necessary to use `Case Is` for the relational items e.g. `Case Is <= 3`, has that changed?

Comment: According to [Select...Case Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) it is optional (as is the `Case` right after the `Select`; however the editor re-inserts it automatically if you try to remove it).

Comment: `In` and `Case` after `Select` were mandatory in Visual Basic 6.0 and VBA.